# Java MultiThread UDP server for audio streaming

Tags: java, multithreading, stream, udp, audio-streaming

I have a java udp server for audio streaming. Server is encoding audio with opus Sending stream to clients with UDP server

I would like to know if you ever worked for sending a stream with multiple thread. Because i dont know how i can share encoded stream between threads.

Because i want to create

1 Thread who listens connections from client and saves ip+port
1 Thread who captures micro and encodes the stream 
1 Thread for each client for sending the encoded stream

Comment: UDP dows not send a stream. UDP does send datagrams, maybe you should switch to TCP when you need a stream. By the way 1 thread per connection in general is a bad design decision. You should think and read about a threadpool which handles client connections and sending data.

Comment: the sound stream send is just datagrams, TCP is not fast enough for voice streaming. I will make a threadpool as you said because management of threads are difficult.  But with a thread pool i will have the same problem. How share correctly the encoded sound stream between threads? I thought a thread-safe stream but it seems complicated and brings some other problems.